# How to validate unbound fields

Tags: symfony

I have a form 'ChallengeType'. Which has these fields:

1) Embedded form team1
input field username

2) Embedded form team2
input field username

3) Place
a challenge field

4) Date
a challenge field

The username field for each team has been set like this in the TeamType class:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('player_one', 'fos_user_username', array(
            'property_path' => false,
            'attr' => array('class' => 'player_autocomplete')
        ))
    ;
}
```

Because the property_path is set to false, this username field is unbound.

I would like to validate this field, to make sure that the inputted username is an existing one. How can I do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by following way

```
$builder-> addValidator(new CallbackValidator(function(FormInterface $form){
  $player_one = $form['player_one'];
    //validate
      //validation failed?
      $form['player_one']->addError(new FormError("error message"));
});
```