# symfony2: how to validate a property which is not mapped to the entity ('property_path' => false)

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

I'm having a registration form, which contains input fields, almost every field mapped to a property of the User class. But there are some fields which are not mapped. Validation is done via annotations in the User class.

My question is: how do I validate those fields which are not mapped?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853913/how-to-validate-unbound-fields

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12911686/symfony-validate-form-with-mapped-false-form-fields